# Handle JSON Response - Both JsonArray & JsonObject for same Attribute based on response - Java - Android Retrofit

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit2

i am getting two types of Json Response.

One is:

```
{
  "status": true,
  "datetime": "",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "xxx"
    }
  ]
}
```

Another Format is:

```
{
  "status": true,
  "datetime": "",
  "data":
  {
    "name": "aaa"
  }
}
```

Object "data" will be a `JsonObject` on some response and it will be a `JsonArray` on some response , how to handle both type of request.

I am using Retrofit api for communication.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `GsonConverterFactory`, you can use `JsonElement` to represent both `JsonObject` and `JsonArray` as both of them extends `JsonElement`.

Then you can use the method `JsonElement#isJsonArray()` to check and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get "data" as JsonElement and check it: JsonObject or JsonArray respectively. For example, you can write custom `JsonDeserializer`:

```
class CustomDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<YourModel> {

    @Override
    public YourModel deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject responseObj = json.asJsonObject;
        JsonElement data = responseObj.get("data");
        // get your dinamic data
        if (data.isJsonObject()) {
        // parse as object
        } else if (data.isJsonArray()) {
        // parse as array
        }
    }
```